# An issue with proof of ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am going through a proof of ratio test. Assuming $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ tends to $l$ where $0 \leq l < 1$ One chooses $r$ such that $l < r < 1$. It follows that there is $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < r$. I do not understand how this last inequality follows.  My work: supposing that $r = l + \epsilon$ then $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - l | < \epsilon$ then if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - l > 0 $ the inequality follows. However, I do not think this inequality holds.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ratios. If $b_n \to l <r$ can you show (using definition of limit)  that $b_n <r$ for $n$ sufficiently large?

Comment: $|x-l|<\epsilon$ implies $x <l+\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\ b_n \to l\in\mathbb{R}\ $ and $\ r>l.\ $ Note that $\ r-l>0,\ $ and so the definition of " $\ b_n \to l\in\mathbb{R}\ $ " tells us that $\ \exists\ N\ $ such that $\ \vert b_n - l \vert < r - l\quad \forall\ n\geq N.$

For each $\ n\geq N,\ $ either $\ l > b_n\ $ or $\ b_n\geq l\ $ and we consider these two cases separately.

If $\ l>b_n,\ $ then $\ r>l>b_n,\ $ that is, $\ r> b_n.$

If $\ b_n \geq l,\ $ then $\ b_n - l \geq 0, \implies \vert b_n - l \vert = b_n - l.\ $ Since $\ \vert b_n - l \vert < r - l\ $ and $\ \vert b_n - l \vert = b_n - l,\ $ it follows that $\ b_n - l < r-l,\implies b_n < r.$

We have shown $\ \exists\ N\ $ such that $\ b_n < r\quad \forall\ n\geq N,\ $ as desired.

Now let $\ b_n:= \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n},\ $ and your original question related to the ratio test is answered.